# How does MessageEndpointMappings know to setup a subscription vs outgoing messages?

Tags: nservicebus

I see MessageEndpointMappings section in my App.config and it just keeps confusing me.

Sometimes it looks like it sets of a client to subscribe to another queue (like this one does):

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
 <MessageEndpointMappings>      
   <add Messages="MyServiceBus.MessageHub.Contracts" Endpoint="MessageHub"/>
 </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

But other times it seems to be used to configure outgoing messages to other queues:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
 <MessageEndpointMappings>      
   <add Messages="ServiceBus.MessageHub.InternalMessages" Endpoint="MessageHub"/>
 </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

But really, there is no difference between the two of them.  **So how does it know when to setup a subscription and when to setup for sending messages?**

Or is it really doing both all the time and I just don't use both?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Essentially, what you're declaring with the `MessageEndpointMappings` element, is "who is the *owner* of the specified messages?"

Another way to view it, is that this is the direction of *the service dependency* - not the message flow, because that is determined by whether messages get `Send`t or `Publish`d.

Therefore, in order to be able to send messages and subscribe to messages from a given service, you declare an endpoint mapping in the sender/subscriber end.

And then, when the sender/subscriber has an endpoint mapping that points to another service *and a handler for a message included in that endpoint mapping*, NServiceBus is nice enough to automatically subscribe to that message (unless you disable the auto-subscription with `DoNotAutoSubscribe()`) - because, logically, that must mean that the sender/subscriber wishes to subscribe to the given message.

When you think about it this way, I think it makes sense. Hope you feel so too :)